# Как запустить без метода main

Tags: java

Всем привет. Есть такой код из книги Head First Java Second Edition 12 chapter:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class myDrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.orange);  
        g.fillRect(20, 50, 100, 100); 
    }
}
```

При запуске из command-line выдает такую ошибку:

```
Error: Main method not found in class myDrawPanel, please define the main method
 as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Собственно вопрос. Как запустить этот скрипт без метода main ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Очевидно, что этот код является лишь частью программы. Судя по оглавлению, недостающие части следует искать в той же главе книги.

Либо этот фрагмент является модификацией ранее написанной программы - либо, напротив, работающая программа будет собрана авторами к концу главы. В любом случае, главу следует читать внимательнее.

PS судя по тому, что вы вообще задаетесь вопросом запуска программы без метода main - вы недостаточно внимательно читали главы 1-2.

Comment: Скорее всего он показан для примера, но он обрезан т.к. рядом есть картинка что должно быть после запуска, рядом негде нету недостающих частей, что же, в принципе логика скрипта понятно, оставлю ее так без запуска:) Хотелось просто посмотреть что выйдет.

Comment: К моменту, когда вам объясняют рисование прямоугольников на панели - вам должны были уже объяснить, как в принципе запускать приложения на Swing. Попробуйте воспользоваться этими знаниями.

Answer (score 4):

В общем случае никак. Точкой входа в программу на Java является метод `main` какого-либо класса. 
Есть ухищрения, с помощью которых можно выполнить часть кода вне `main` и не получить ошибку, но это не ваш случай.

Answer (score 1):

Может кому пригодиться... Разобрался как запустить, точнее как правильно создать метод main.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

//Рыжий квадрат
public class frameTest1a{


    JButton button;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        frameTest1a gui = new frameTest1a();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        MyDrawPanel drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {  
        public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.orange);
            g.fillRect(20,50,100,100);
        }

    }

}
```