# Ошибка - main method not found in class

Tags: java, javafx, исключения, main

> Error: Main method not found in class AC.processlist, please define the main method as:
>      public static void main(String[] args)
>   or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Хотя метод main есть. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: тогда необходимо наследоваться от javafx.application.Application

Comment: метод main должен быть объявлен именно так и никак иначе `public static void main(String[] args)` (throws можно любое объявить)

Answer (score 2):

В сообщении об ошибке уже есть подсказка: "**must extend javafx.application.Application**". Необходимо наследоваться от **javafx.application.Application**, иначе вы не сможете запустить своё приложение. Возможно, вы просто забыли подключить этот пакет.

Подобные вопросы уже задавались и имеют ответы, вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435736/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8C-or-a-javafx-application-class-must-extend-javafx-application-applic). И еще [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430516/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-main).

Но лучше всего, конечно, читать документацию и желательно на английском.

[Ссылка](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm) на официальную документацию с примером создания простейшего приложения.

P.S. Возможно еще и такое решение, если с кодом всё в порядке: перезапустить IDE и провести чистку проекта с перекомпиляцией.

Comment: код не менял, просто сделал launch as java applet
все стало работать

Comment: Тогда проблема была в конфигурации.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой же ошибкой. Программа запускалась не из основного класса с метода main, а из класса без этого метода. Помогло явной указание, из какого класса будет запускаться программа.